# Vlookup for string within column

Tags: xml, excel, vba, vlookup

I have to build a CSV from pulling data from 2 other CSV's

First, the column linking them together looks like this:

CSV 1

```
Column A | Column B | Column C
   Honda |  I_1999  |  Red
   Honda |  I_1999  |  Blue   
   Honda |  I_1999  |  Green
   Toyota|  I_1998  |  Yellow
```

CSV 2

```
Column A | Column B  | Column C
   Honda |  1999.xml |  Coupe
   Honda |  1999.xml |  Sedan
   Toyota|  1998.xml |  Coupe
   Toyota|  1998.xml |  Sedan
```

Is there a way to vlookup a partial string? Say vlookup string after "I_" in CSV 1 Column B to string before ".xml" CSV 2 Column B.

Second, how do I put the referenced data in 1 file once they've been linked up?

I'd like the new CSV to look like this in the end:

```
Column A | Column B |  Column D |  Column E
Honda    |   I_1999 |    Red    |  Coupe 
Honda    |   I_1999 |    Red    |  Sedan
Honda    |   I_1999 |    Blue   |  Coupe 
Honda    |   I_1999 |    Blue   |  Sedan
```

Answer (score 0):

To use VLOOKUP we need something unique, however as per your details you can use the below array formula.

```
=IF($A$1:$A$5=$F$1:$F$5,INDEX($F$1:$H$5,MATCH(RIGHT(B2,4),LEFT($G$1:$G$5),0),"")
```

Press **CTRL+Shift+Enter**

[image]

In the above snap you can see the result in D2 cell instead of "Sedan" "Coupe" exist since its a duplicate match for the same criteria (in VLOOKUP also). You may add one unique ID then try you will get the exact result :)

Answer (score 0):

You should actually be able to do is to create two data tables using ADO and use SQL to do what you want.

Assume that you have the 1st data in range:Sheet1!A1:C3 and the second data in range sheet1!E1:G5. Each data column has a header of A, B, C etc.

[image]

The following query will join as you require.

```
SELECT Data.A AS [Column A],
       Data.B AS [Column B],
       Data.C AS [Column C],
       Data1.C AS [Column D] 
FROM [Sheet1$A1:C3] Data 
INNER JOIN [Sheet1$E1:G5] Data1 
ON Data.A = Data1.A
```

Use the copyfromrecordset to some other range to paste out the resultant data.

[image]

Comment: How can you get the expected results with a non-unique primary key though?